# ER diagram in monitoring and tracking-change system

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema, entity-relationship

im trying to figure out what erd look like when it comes to system that tracking change and monitoring invoice processing case.

Case is : 
Rule is list that containt what vendor need to send to company. It is no need to satisfy all rule (there is 12 rules), but at least vendor has to satisfy some, doesnt matter what is it).
Vendor send invoice to Company, along with checklist, containing rule that satisfied. The invoice must satisfy company rule (there is 12 rule, but company only will check it with checklist from vendor, if vendor only check 4 rule, then company will check that 4). First, the manager get the invoice on his desk. Then he sent it to Secretary. Secretary write incoming invoice to her book, and she sent it to specific sub-area. Sub-area then checking invoice document. If invoice satisfy company's rule, then it processed to the payment, else invoice will threw back to Secretary, to sent back to Vendor.
The manager must able to monitor progress of invoice processing from this system.
Here is my design right now :

```
Vendor -1---sent----N- Invoice -N---verify----N- Company
                         |
                        has
                         |
                        Rule
```

My table design is like this :

```
 Vendor        Invoice           Rule           Verify          Company
--------      -----------       -------        ----------      --------
 + id          + id              + id           + id            + id
 + vendor      + vendorid        + rule         + invoiceid     + user
 + username    + projectname                    + userid        +password
 + passwd      + projectvalue                   + phase
```

Im wondering where to put table for monitoring change (which is contain how far invoice processed (phase) and who's processing it), so that manager can monitor how far, who's involved, which process have done and haven't.
Am i design it wrong?

Comment: i am wondering what your concrete question is? Can you pls simplify the problem

Comment: I think the problem is that you try to mix behaviour with structural design.Do you have a database structur and do you use it as simple model. The logic or behaviour has to be implemented using a programming language!